# How to separate data on subplots?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to extract data from multiple files and plot it separately, using subplots. But my plots repeat in all the subplots, how can I separate it?

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,3, sharex=True, figsize=(10,7))
axs = axs.ravel()
xs = []
ys = []

filename = sorted(glob.glob('*.txt'))# create a list of files
for file in filename:
    data = np.loadtxt(file,delimiter='\t', skiprows=2)
for x,y in data:
    x = data[:,0]
    y = data[:,1]
xs.append(x)
ys.append(y)

for i in range(len(filename)):
   for j,k in zip(xs,ys):
        axs[i].plot(j, k)
```

It is showing one fig with 6 of the same plot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for i in range(len(filename)):
   for j,k in zip(xs,ys):
        axs[i].plot(j, k)
```

You are creating the same plots (inner loop) for every subplot (outer loop).

What you should do, instead, is only plot in the relevant subplots.

For example, assuming `len(xs) == len(ys) == 6`, you could replace the nested loops from above with the following (**AND** removing the `axs = axs.ravel()`).

```
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(xs, ys)):
    ij = np.unravel_index(i, axs.shape)
    axs[ij].plot(x, y)
```

**NOTE**: You may also want to double check what you are doing with the generation of `xs` and `ys`. Perhaps it is only an indentation issue since with your code `len(xs) == len(ys) == 1`, but there may be more to it, since you both loop through `data` and assign to the looping variables, which is bad practice since it may lead to inconsistent behaviors.

Comment: Hey, Thank you! It worked. I think I understand. I was looping through the same plot over and over!

Comment: @AngelLira Glad it helped! If that solved your problem, you may consider accepting the answer.